# Remove view of particular class from window

Tags: ios, swift

Is there anyway to remove a view from the uiapplication window of a particular class?

I have a class called MainView that is the top header bar for the app on the main screen. I have a view that gets added after that where users can swipe up and down to different screens but on the screen where a user swipes up or down too the MainView bar at the top needs to be removed. How should I go about this? Should I try removing this MainView class from the UIApplication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your MainView instance is added directly to the window, you can get the array of the window's subviews. Then iterate over the subviews until you find a view that is type `MainView` and remove it from the window.

```
NSArray *subviews = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.subviews;
for (UIView *view in subviews)
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[MainView class]])
    {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: need this answer in swift

Answer (score 1):

```
[yourSubview removeFromSuperview];
```